Incorrect symmetric part of geometric product in Geometric Algebra. Where did I go wrong?
Consider symmetric part of geometric product:
$$ 
\frac{1}{2}(ab+ba) = \frac{1}{2} \bigl((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2\bigr) \tag1
$$
Wiki says: "From the law of cosines on the triangle formed by the vectors its value is $|a||b|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.
Wiki says: $c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$.
Let's substitute $a^2+b^2 = c^2+2ab\cos\theta$ in $(1)$:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}(ab+ba) 
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigl((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2\bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigl((a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)\bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigl((a+b)^2-c^2-2ab\cos\theta)\bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$
It's obtained scalar product with "-": $\frac{1}{2}(ab+ba) = -(a*b)$.
But symmetric part must be $(a*b)$.
Where did I go wrong?
Thanks.

The triangle formed by vectors $a$ and $b$ has a third side $c = a - b$ opposite the angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$. In other words, the Law of Cosines in terms of these vectors looks like
$$
(a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos\theta 
$$
Replace $b$ by $-b$ and we obtain
$$
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos\theta, 
$$
which yields the result you expect.
